# Is every unitary ring finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

I'm puzzled by the following:

if $R$ is a unitary ring then $R$ is generated by $1_R$, denoted as $$R = \langle 1_R \rangle. $$ can we conclude that every unitary ring is finitely generated? I know the answer is no, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated, although we can express $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\langle 1 \rangle$. Can somebody help explain what's causing my confusion?

Comment: Write out very carefully your definition of "finitely generated" as a ring.

Comment: An ideal in R is finitely generated if and only if there exists a finite set of elements in R that generates it.

Comment: The subring generated by a set $X$ and the ideal generated by a set $X$ inside a ring $R$ can be different.  Which do you mean?

Comment: Are you suggesting that stating that  R is finitely generated as a ring is distinct from expressing that the ideal R (as an ideal of it self) is finitely generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you are confusing being finitely generated as an ideal and being finitely generated as a module.

Taking any ring $R$, it is true that $R=(1)$ as an ideal, which is equivalent to say that $R=\langle 1\rangle _R$ as an $R$-module.
So $\mathbb{Q}=\langle 1\rangle _\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module (i.e. as an ideal and thus, according to your definition, as a ring).
However $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. If you consider $\mathbb{Q}$ with this structure, as you correctly pointed out, it is not finitely generated. But this means that it is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, not as an ideal ($=\mathbb{Q}$-module).

Comment: Okay thank you, so Q is finitely generated as a ring? That's right?

Comment: Usually one does not define the notion of being finitely generated as a ring because if you consider being finitely generated as a ring as being finitely generated as an ideal, then every unitary ring is finitely generated (by $1$). So yes, using this notion $\mathbb{Q}$ is finitely generated as a ring (but as i said one does not usually defines this notion since it is trivially true for any ring).

Comment: Thank you. By the way, we can infer that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Noetherian $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but we cannot deduce that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Noetherian ring. Is this right?

Comment: Yep, you are right (btw $\mathbb{Q}$ **is** a noetherian ring since it is a field)

Comment: Thank you very much, well understand.

Comment: The actual problem is distinguishing being finitely generated as an ideal or a submodule of $R$ (the same thing if $R$ is commutative) and being *finitely generated as a ring*.  The notion of $R$ being finitely generated as a ring is a perfectly fine one: it means there is a finite subset of $R$ such that the smallest subring of $R$ containing that subset is the whole ring.  The reason that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated as a ring is that any finite subset can only contain finitely many primes as factors of its denominators, so there will always be a $\frac{1}{p}$ that is not obtained.

Comment: @AllenBell I made a mistake in the comment saying that the notion is not used and you are right about that. But the OP, in the comments to the question, said the he/she intendend being finitely generated as a ring as being finitely generated as an ideal so I answered that